# How to use custom data from JSON in ForEach SwiftUI

Tags: json, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I have JSON file with custom data. **Goal** is to use this data in `PostCard()` in `ForEach(){}`. But evetytime i try to use `user` inside, i receive this error in VStack *Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate*.

**My JSON convertor func looks like this:**

```
let userResponse: [UserResponse] = load("users.json")



func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String, as type: T.Type = T.self) -> T {
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

**Custom data types:**

```
struct UserResponse: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
   public var id: Int
   public var username: String
   public var avatar: String
   public var postOne: String
   public var postTwo: String
   public var postThree: String
   public var postFour: String
   public var story: String
   public var likes: Int
   public var commentNumber: Int
   public var location: String
   public var comment: String
   public var name: String
   public var followers: Int
   public var following: Int
   public var postNumbers: Int
   public var bio: String
   public var locationPic: String
}
```

**I initialize it inside of a Child View:**

```
var user : UserResponse
```

```
ZStack{
   VStack{
      ForEach(userResponse){user in
         HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5){             
            PostCard(user: user)
               .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))

            PostCard(user: user)
               .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 5))

         }.shadow(color: Color("greySec"), radius: 3, x: 0, y: 0)
      }
   }.navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
      .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```

My `PostCard` struct looks like this:

```
var user : UserResponse
```

```
VStack(spacing: 10){
   HStack(spacing: 5){
      VStack(spacing: 10){
         Image(user.postOne)
            .resizable().frame(height: 290)

         HStack{
            Text(user.comment)
               .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .medium))
               .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 5))
         }
      }
      .background(Color("whiteAndBlack"))
      .cornerRadius(5)
      .foregroundColor(.black)
   }
}
```

**Question** :  Is there anyone who knows how to use JSON data inside of `ForEach(){}`?  My goal is to create this view using various JSON data for each PostCard.

Comment: are you trying to do a `ForEach` over the `[UserResponse]` array? In your code, it seems to be over `self.user`, which is a single object.

Comment: @NewDev I've edited code. I've been trying to use `userResponse` (converted JSON data) in ForEach and List, but nothing works.  If I use `userResponse` in `List`, then XCode says me that i have to pass **user: user** to all previous views (the view with ZStack presented here is the second child of content view). When i passed **user: user** to each previous view, it said that i don't have it in SceneDelegate. So the circle is infinite..

Comment: @NewDev if i use `userResponse` in ForEach i face the same problem. Xcode just leads me to the SceneDelegate so i passed value `user:user` to `let contentView = ContentView()` ,but everytime i pass and use `var user : UserResponse`  is says that SceneDelegate doesn't have initializers. And Finally when i put initialisers inside `var user : UserResponse(id: Int, comment: String etc.) ` it says that i the value of the `Int.Type` doesn't match `Int` required type  (for id init.).

Comment: I guess, I don't understand what errors you're running into. Based on the code here, `PostCard(user: user)` should work if `userResponse` in your "ZStack" view is an array of `[UserResponse]` (btw, this naming is confusing). Other errors seem to be not captured in the code you posted. And, if you are decoding the JSON data into an object, then this information is not really relevant to you question.